# How to create an object from InputOutputArray in OpenCvSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using the `OpenCvSharp` in a `C#` solution and I would like to calibrate a camera using the method `Cv2.CalibrateCamera`. To use this function, I need to create some objects of type `OpenCvSharp.InputOutputArray`. However, it seems that the class `OpenCvSharp.InputOutputArray` does not have a constructor. I have also tried the method `InputOutputArray.Create()`, but it returns an `OutputArray` object. How can I create an instance of this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InputOutputArray` parameters to `CalibrateCamera` are the output values `cameraMatrix` and `distCoeffs`. You can use an empty initialized `Mat` for those parameters. OpenCV will resize them and fill them with the return values. This example shows the syntax. (You will, of course, need to populate `image`, `objectPoints`, and `imagePoints` with real data before calling `CalibrateCamera`.)

This example uses `List<Mat>` for `objectPoints` and `imagePoints` but they can be any collection type that implements `IEnumerable` (e.g. `Mat[]`).

```
Mat image;
List<Mat> objectPoints; // input to CalibrateCamera
List<Mat> imagePoints; // input to CalibrateCamera
Mat cameraMatrix = new Mat(); // output from CalibrateCamera
Mat distCoeffs = new Mat(); // output from CalibrateCamera
Mat[] rvecs; // output from CalibrateCamera
Mat[] tvecs; // output from CalibrateCamera
CalibrationFlags flags = CalibrationFlags.FixAspectRatio;

//Populate image, objectPoints, and imagePoints with real data before calling CalibrateCamera

Cv2.CalibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, image.Size(), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, out rvecs, out tvecs, flags);
```